# How to make first letter of NSString Capital in iPhone dev

Tags: iphone

I am having a NSString to which I am trimming at the start and end for blank spaces. Now I want to make the first alphabet or letter of the string to appear as capital.

Is there any short available or I need to take the first alphabet and convert it to capital on my own.

tnx.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to do it by hand. This is one of those things that has been built into categories so often by so many people that Apple probably doesn't dare add it as an actual method since it would generate category collisions.

```
NSString *firstCapChar = [[string substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString];
NSString *cappedString = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:firstCapChar];
```

There are of course many other solutions using NSMutableString or any other way you like to do it using unichar or whatever.

Comment: This would not enforce other letters to be lowercase. A complementary solution for that case would be something like: text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [[text substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString], [[text substringFromIndex:1] lowercaseString]];

Answer (score 7):

```
- (NSString *)capitalizedString
```

will make all words in the string initially capitalized.  If you only have one or two words in your string, this may be what you want.

[Here is the NSString class reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/capitalizedString).

Comment: No I just want the first alphabet to be capital and not the whole string or the complete words.

Comment: It's strange, but seems like it doesn't available for ios?

Answer (score 0):

@BrianRamsay answer is good but it makes all words capitalized instead of the first one only. I created a comfortable category for @RobNapier answer:

```
@interface NSString (Initcap)

@property (readonly) NSString *initcappedString;

@end

@implementation NSString (Initcap)

- (NSString *)initcappedString {
    NSString *firstCapChar = [[self substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString];
    return [self stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)
                                         withString:firstCapChar];
}

@end
```

Next use it like this `str.initcappedString`.